# Lead Capture Popup in Drupal

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a solution to implement a lead capture [lightbox popup](https://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) form in Drupal 7. Is there module that would do this? Basically if a user is on a page after a certain amount of time (~10 or 15 seconds), a lightbox popup would go over the page they are looking at and ask them for their email.

Comment: I'm looking for a module that allows to display a popup once after a certain delay on a page load.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Popup on load]

> The module allows to display a popup once after a certain delay on a
>   page load. This fills a gap in popup modules family (Popups, Popup),
>   which are designed to show popups only after a click on an HTML
>   element, or to implement a complex behavior like modal dialog forms.

You can specify paths on which you need to display the popup without appropriate delay

Comment: Which module is the one you are referring to above? Is there anyway to attach a form on the popup?

Comment: Which module is this?

Comment: It is basically a module which shows popup after some time as specified in the settings, and using rules modules you can set the action and modal dialog form has the option of attaching form

Comment: How do I find this module you are referring to? What's the name of it? I'd like to download it.

Comment: I believe the module mentioned above is popup_onload: https://drupal.org/project/popup_onload